# AngularJS records is not display in listing page untill page is not refresh..?

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter-3

When I insert form in angularJS ,After insert of my data in database.
My record is not display until page is reload.

its My Js Controller:-

```
 $scope.mywarehousess = [];

  $http({
      url:'warehouse/warehouse_fetchdata',
      method: "POST"
  }).success(function (data) {
      $scope.mywarehousess = data;
  });
```

HTML View or Listing Page Code:-

```
    <tr>

        <th>SL. NO.</th>
        <th>Warehouse Name</th>
        <th>Warehouse Address</th>
        <th>Manage</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

    <tr ng-repeat="warehouse in mywarehousess">

        <td>{{$index +1}}</td>
        <!--<td>{{warehouse.warehouse_key}}</td>-->
        <td>{{warehouse.warehouse_name}}</td>
        <td>{{warehouse.warehouse_address}}</td>

        <td>
            <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#update" ng-click="getEditWarehousedata(warehouse.warehouse_id)" class="table-action-btn"
                style="cursor:pointer;"><i class="md md-edit"></i></a>
            <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#del" ng-click="getEditWarehousedata(warehouse.warehouse_id)" class="table-action-btn"><i class="md md-delete"></i></a>
        </td>

    </tr>
</tbody>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbZra.png)

Codeigniter Controller:-

```
 public function warehouse_fetchdata(){
   $result = $this->user_model->select_all_warehouse(['warehouse_status'=>1]);
         //print_r($result);
         echo json_encode($result);
  }
```

Add js Controller:-

$scope.form = {};

```
$scope.savewarehouse = function () {
    $http({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'warehouse/insert_warehouse',
        data: $scope.form,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    }).success(function (data)
    {

    });
};
```

Comment: your model is mywarehousess you need to update this with the new data in order to update view

Comment: where are you using `units` in your html template?

Comment: Sorry thats was wrong now i am upload correct one.

Comment: can you edit your post with the data you getting here console.log(data);?

Comment: I am using console.log(data) for my debuging code.remove

Comment: i mean can you post the json you are getting from response, also try this $scope.mywarehousess = data.data;

Comment: please add the code of your `add funciton`

Comment: for my js controller or my codeigniter controller.

Comment: from your js controller

Comment: Please check .let me know its very urgent.

Comment: `console.log($scope.form)` and `console.log($scope.form)` and send results

Comment: no its not work. SORRY !!

Comment: no you send me console result from browser. I wanted to see whats coming

Comment: Any Others sol ..

Comment: Have you tried pushing the element into your array like  $scope.mywarehousess.push($scope.form);

Answer (score 0):

After adding you need to update the `$scope` variable

So, in your success response do, `$scope.mywarehousess.push($scope.form)`

```
$scope.savewarehouse = function () {
    $http({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'warehouse/insert_warehouse',
        data: $scope.form,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    }).success(function (data)
    {
       $scope.mywarehousess.push($scope.form)
    });
};
```

Comment: Sorry But STill Not Working.

Comment: can you send console.log results